# Is this an LCD backlight failure?

Tags: display, lcd, backlight

When I either connect my monitor to my computer or turn it on, it will display an image from the computer for like a second, and then the screen will go black, but the monitor stays on and does not blink the power light like it does when it's not getting a signal. Is this a bad backlight? I'd like to be sure before I order the part to try to fix it.

Edit: Well, I just determine I can see stuff if I look real closing, so probably backlight or the inverter? If it is the inverter, what kind do I have to buy? If it is the backlight where I can get one for a 24" monitor or anything else it might be? It is a Samsung SyncMaster 2433BW.

Answer (score 0):

That could be the backlight inverter, but I'm not certain. Could also be a controller problem. Inverters are fairly cheap, so it might be worth it to buy a replacement just to investigate.

Comment: Do you know where I could buy this stuff? I can see a faint outline of what is supposed to be on the screen btw.

Comment: That does sound like the backlight inverter. You could try finding a contact in the parts department of whoever made the monitor, often they'll be willing to send you a part at the same price they charge service partners, but they won't advertise this. Your best bet might be calling Samsung support and pestering them about ordering parts. If you can't find a contact there, eBay is probably your best bet.

Comment: Hmmm, I suppose it is worth a shot. Probably won't get anywhere though. I once tried to get logitech to send me a new keyboard leg, and they basically told me that I should buy a new keyboard from them instead. I can't just get any inverter though and then just have the monitor settings adjustments not work or something like that?

Comment: You probably could, but you'd need to make sure the specs match up properly... it might not be easy, but it's possible.